# Secure Canvas Clarification

Tags: facebook, canvas

Been reading the docs about canvas and secure canvas, mainly due to the requirement that we provide a secure url before october 1. However, I cannot determine with any sense of certainty that we actually need to use a secure canvas.

If we only want to provide the ability for users to "login" and "like", do we even need a canvas? As far as I can tell, a canvas is something that facebook creates an iframe for, which points to a canvas url we provide, which is ultimately displayed on the facebook site.

Any clarification would be appreciated.

Comment: The SO post is over 2 years old with no references to secure canvas. The responses refer to an old blog post as well. Was hoping for a more up-to-date answer.

Comment: Appreciate the responses. To be honest, I am not too concerned with the "politics" of why people will or will not accept answers. I simply ask what I think are relevant questions and hope for the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apps accessed via facebook.com (i.e apps.facebook.com/something or via a Page Tab) will need to be accessible over HTTPS - you won't need to make your site to be available over HTTPS for the social plugins or off-Facebook API usage to work

The blog post with the details is https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/499/
Specifically: `All Apps on Facebook (Canvas and Page Tabs) must support HTTPS by October 1.`

Comment: Thanks for the link, this is new info. Perhaps I am being too naive in trying to get a more black and white answer to the difference between "login" and "like" and apps which use a "canvas" or "page tab".

Comment: If users access your app because it's installed as a tab on a Facebook Page, or if users access your app via apps.facebook.com/yourapp - those parts of the app will need to be accessible over HTTPS - if your app runs on mysite.com, and only directs to facebook for the authorisation step, it does not need to be accessible over https